# MateralizeCSS, how to center checkboxes

Tags: html, css, materialize

Below is my code showing checkboxes not aligning. The CDN for Materialize.css is added to allow troubleshooting.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<form action="#" class="center-align">

  <p class="center-align">
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <span>test</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p class="center-align">
    <label class="center">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <span>not aligned</span>
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
```

The checkboxes are not aligning, how come?

[image]

Comment: Is there a css code portion? I ran this in js fiddle. It is aligned there? https://jsfiddle.net/ox02zv5b/2/

Comment: Please add CSS and JS if needed in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

      <div class="row">
      <div class="col offset-s5">
            <form action="#">
                    <p>
                        <label class="center">
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                         <span>test</span>
                        </label>
                    </p>
                   <p>
                        <label class="center">
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                         <span>not aligned</span>
                        </label>
                    </p>
                </form>
        </div>
        </div>
```

You should get familiar with the [Materialize Grid System](https://materializecss.com/grid.html) and use that, your way only aligns the text and not the Checkboxes itself.

Comment: How does this bring it to the center? I understand the grid system a little, but if you offset it by 5, this makes the column 7 colums wide. How does that make it center?

Comment: @HandleBars1 The page itself is 12 colums wide. If you offset it by 5 it will beginn at 6 means exactly in the middle, this is a smooth workaround, and you could make it 1 column wide and still offset by 5 and it would still be in the middle but wouldnt take the whole page. I hope you can follow ^^

Comment: Right, page is 12 columns wide. So if 12-5 = 7? So why does it start at six :/. Is it exclusive whenever u offset? thanks for reply

I think I understand now.
Column starts at 1, offset by 5 = 1+5 = 6. , not subtracting